# Geometrical linearization in continuum mechanics

Tags: continuum-mechanics, linearized-theory

In continuum mechanics, we often make use of "physical and geometrical linearization", e. g. during derivation the Navier-Cauchy equations (c. f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_elasticity). I understand that physical linearization refers to the assumption that the constituive matrix $\mathbf{C}$ in our constitutive equation $$\mathbf{\sigma}=\mathbf{C}\cdot\mathbf{\epsilon}$$ is constant and does not depend on $\epsilon$ to facilitate calculations. But what is the point of "geometrical linearization"? To my understanding, it means using only the "symmetrcial part" of the displacement gradient $\mathbf{H}$, which defines the "engineering strains $\epsilon_i$ we use in our constitutive equation: $$\epsilon:=\epsilon_i=\mathbf{H^S}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot(\mathbf{H}+\mathbf{H^T})$$If we look at $\mathbf{H}$ and $\epsilon_i$ in a 2D case (merely for the sake of simplicity, 3D is no different), there seems to be little difference between them: $$\mathbf{H}=\begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{du}{dx} & \frac{du}{dy}\\
    \frac{dv}{dx} & \frac{dv}{dy}\\
    \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\mathbf{\epsilon_i}=\begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{du}{dx} & \frac{1}{2}\cdot(\frac{du}{dy}+\frac{dv}{dx})\\
    \frac{1}{2}\cdot(\frac{du}{dy}+\frac{dv}{dx}) & \frac{dv}{dy}\\
    \end{pmatrix}$$
In comparison, they both consist of the same derivatives and the only thing we achieve is a symmetrical strain tensor (for which we pay a price in the form of erroneous strains for rotations). So how exactly does that make things easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine two infinitesimally close points $a$ and $b$, the difference between their squared distances before and after the deformation can be measured by $((I+H)(b-a))^T (I+H)(b-a)-(b-a)^T(b-a)$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. So it is possible to think of the nonlinear strain tensor as $(I+H)^T(I+H)-I$. The accurate measurement can be replaced through the geometric linearization you described by $H^T+H$, up to a scaling factor. So there is some loss in accuracy in $H^T H$, which is of order $O(|H|^2)$, and a gain in efficiency in calculation.

Comment: Yes, when we identify $I+H$ as the deformation gradient $F$, we arrive at the definition of Lagrange strain $E=0.5\cdot(F^T\cdot F-I)$ which is based on the squared difference of vector lengths. $H$ itself does not seem to be a suitable strain measure. Comparing the definitions of Lagrange and engineering strain, I see that the latter indeed requires less computational effort since we omit the quadratic term as you pointed out. If $u_x=f(x)$, $u_y=g(y)$ and $u_z=h(z)$ (i. e. if the displacement components are parallel to their respective axes), the engineering strains are an exact measure.

Comment: Yeah, it's true when the deformation gradient is diagonal, the engineering strain will contain all the information, which is also the case as you mentioned, when there's no rotation of the principal stretch directions from the original coordinate axes.

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually have another related question, I think I'll edit my original post.

Comment: Ah nevermind, I think I'll post a new question if necessary. Anyways, merry christmas my friend ;)

Comment: Merry Christmas :)